# How to Use jQuery to Search/Replace/Change URL While Keeping ID Parameter and Not Touching HTML?

Tags: jquery

On my site, I want to search/replace all instances of one URL (that has different IDs, otherwise it is the same) to another.

For example, my site could have the following hyperlinked URLs (they are just examples, again, the IDs will be different):

- https://example.com/_layouts/15/listform.aspx?PageType=6&ListId=%7B6DDF7ABCX%2D5A27%2D4BEB%2DB4F9%2D158FAA3F0B34%7D&ID=7
- https://example.com/_layouts/15/listform.aspx?PageType=6&ListId=%7B6DDF7ABCX%2D5A27%2D4BEB%2DB4F9%2D158FAA3F0B34%7D&ID=35
- https://example.com/_layouts/15/listform.aspx?PageType=6&ListId=%7B6DDF7ABCX%2D5A27%2D4BEB%2DB4F9%2D158FAA3F0B34%7D&ID=100
- https://example.com/_layouts/15/listform.aspx?PageType=6&ListId=%7B6DDF7ABCX%2D5A27%2D4BEB%2DB4F9%2D158FAA3F0B34%7D&ID=9434

and so I would want the new URLs to be

- https://example.com/Lists/Your%20Col/Item/editifs.aspx?ID=7&Source=https://example.com/Lists/Your%20Col/AO12.aspx&DefaultView=AO
- https://example.com/Lists/Your%20Col/Item/editifs.aspx?ID=35&Source=https://example.com/Lists/Your%20Col/AO12.aspx&DefaultView=AO
- https://example.com/Lists/Your%20Col/Item/editifs.aspx?ID=100&Source=https://example.com/Lists/Your%20Col/AO12.aspx&DefaultView=AO
- https://example.com/Lists/Your%20Col/Item/editifs.aspx?ID=9434&Source=https://example.com/Lists/Your%20Col/AO12.aspx&DefaultView=AO

**How can I achieve my desired result with jQuery without touching the following HTML?**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('a[href^="http://"]').each(function() {
    var oldUrl = $(this).attr("href"); // Get current url
    var newUrl = oldUrl.replace("https://example.com/_layouts/15/listform.aspx?PageType=6&amp;ListId=%7B6DDF7B64%2D5A27%2D4BEB%2DB4F9%2D158FAA3F0B34%7D&amp;", "https://example.com/Lists/Your%20Col/Item/editifs.aspx?Source=https://example.com/Lists/Your%20Col/AO12.aspx&DefaultView=AO"); // Create new url
    $(this).attr("href", newUrl); // Set herf value
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="https://example.com/_layouts/15/listform.aspx?PageType=6&amp;ListId=%7B6DDF7B64%2D5A27%2D4BEB%2DB4F9%2D158FAA3F0B34%7D&amp;ID=7">This is a link</a>
<a href="https://example.com/_layouts/15/listform.aspx?PageType=6&amp;ListId=%7B6DDF7B64%2D5A27%2D4BEB%2DB4F9%2D158FAA3F0B34%7D&amp;ID=35">This is a link</a>
<a href="https://example.com/_layouts/15/listform.aspx?PageType=6&amp;ListId=%7B6DDF7ABCX%2D5A27%2D4BEB%2DB4F9%2D158FAA3F0B34%7D&amp;ID=100">This is a link</a>
<a href="https://example.com/_layouts/15/listform.aspx?PageType=6&amp;ListId=%7B6DDF7B64%2D5A27%2D4BEB%2DB4F9%2D158FAA3F0B34%7D&amp;ID=9434">This is a link</a>
```

Comment: And your site is HTML files that you're trying to edit as a one-off with your text editor?

Comment: @Tomalak its SharePont so this is the way it has to be done unfortunately. if it was html or php, or anything more logical, i wouldn't need jQuery to rewrite URLs

Comment: Oh you want to rewrite *on the client side*? Huh... why not on the server side?

Comment: @Tomalak Yes, on the client side. I can't do it server side, just one of the restrictions of what I'm working with. :/

Comment: Here are the two moving parts you can base your approach on: `$("a").filter(...).each(...)` and [URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams). If you have code to show that fails in a specific way, add it to your question.

Comment: @Tomalak added the failing jquery

Comment: In what way is that failing? (Note that the URL will not actually contain `&amp;`. If it does not replace anything, it's likely because of that. Print the URLs to the console to see what I mean.)

Comment: @Tomalak the &amp; is what's in the code when I view source, for example. it's failing because it's not replacing the URLs

Comment: Yes, the `&amp;` is in the HTML source code. It's not in the URL. Check it.

Comment: @Tomalak i've updated the script and html now so the URLs match, but still no luck :/

Comment: Again. The values in your script match the HTML source code. They do not match the *actual* URLs that your script receives. There is no `&amp;` in those URLs. The `&amp;` **only** exists in the HTML source code. Use `console.log(oldUrl)` to see the actual values.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228626/discussion-between-mike-and-tomalak).